# Add custom module activity in history sub-panel ? can some 1 please guide me on this?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

i am using suitecrm ( fork version of sugarcrm CE)

i have created a two custom modules, "book" and "payment"

in book module detail view,i am able to add history panel by adding one to many relationship with activities but it covers only calls, notes, meeting and email

what i want to do is on payment creation or  any update on payment record
i need to display it under history sub panel(like an entry) like ,calls , notes and meeting sub panel .

Any help will be much appreciated.